# jquery countdown

Tags: jquery, variables, countdown

I am new to programming jquery php. I
want to countdown a php time variable
in jquery. For example time= 31233.
How could i count down this like
mm:ss?

Please help thanks

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var defaultTimer = 400, // Default amount of seconds if url variable is not found
        callback = function() {
            // Will be executed when the timer finishes
            alert("Time is up!");   
        };

    var counter = 1, timer, 
        match = document.location.href.match(/[\?|&]timer=(\d+)/i),
        totalTime = match ? match[1] : defaultTimer;

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (totalTime != -1 && !isNaN(totalTime)) {
            val = 'Time left: ' + (function() {
                var m = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
                if (m < 10) {
                    return '0'.concat(m);
                } else {
                    return m;
                }
            })() + ':' + (function() {
                var s = totalTime % 60;
                if (s < 10) {
                    return '0'.concat(s);
                } else {
                    return s;
                }
            })();

            $('#counter').html(val);
            totalTime--;
        } else {
            window.clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
            callback();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

**You can find an example here**: http://jsfiddle.net/hHD4w/

Comment: @hosaf: Try the above code now. I fixed a few things. You should be getting 0's before numbers if they are less than 10. For example: `1:9` should turn into `01:09`.

Comment: @Shaz how do you add cookie options to this counter so that if a user refreshes the page it wont start all over again? thanks again for your work.

Comment: +1. Any chance for 120 minutes/2 hours to display as 2:00:00, instead of 120:00?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
<span id="countdown"></span>

<script>
var timer = 31233;

setInterval( function() {
    var minute = Math.floor(timer / 60);
    var second = '00' + (timer % 60);
    var val = minute + ':' + second.substring(second.length - 2);
    $('#countdown').html(val);   
    timer--;
}, 1000);
</script>
```

fixed formatting - http://jsfiddle.net/3NYY9/8/

Comment: This doesn't address the issue that the OP wants the `timer` to be a set value from a url variable

Comment: hey ! programming needs a graduate degree?

Comment: @sotiris there is a problem 6:7 > 06:07 how to do that? is there a str_pad function in jquery.?

Comment: @hoasaf I didn't answer your question, I just edited the post. @William Bonar answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out...

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/

... and the demo...

http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: i dont need that much beauty.:D